# Frame.Content, assignment operation not work?

Tags: wpf

Here's a very simple repro: Start up VS2010 or VS2008, new a WPF project (.Net Framework 3.5 sp1), add an empty page (Page1.xaml) to the project.

The rest code is in MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TestFrameContent();
    }

    private void TestFrameContent()
    {
        FrameworkElement fe = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("WpfFrameContentProblem.Page1")) as FrameworkElement;
        Frame frmContainer = new Frame();
        frmContainer.Content = fe;

        Debug.Assert(frmContainer.Content != null, "Content is null");
    }
}
```

Run the app, it will fail on Debug.Assert, indicate that frmContainer.Content == null.

It's really a mystery to me, that a simple assignment will fail. Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not a simple assignment.  Setting the Content property on a Frame actually calls [Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602273.aspx), which sets the content asynchronously.  You will need to handle the [Navigated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.navigated.aspx) event, which "occurs when the content that is being navigated to has been found, and is available from the Content property, although it may not have completed loading."

```
private void TestFrameContent()
{
    FrameworkElement fe = Activator.CreateInstance(
        Type.GetType("WpfFrameContentProblem.Page1")) as FrameworkElement;
    Frame frmContainer = new Frame();
    frmContainer.Content = fe;
    frmContainer.Navigated += delegate(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // This will succeed
        Debug.Assert(frmContainer.Content != null, "Content is null");
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you. 
I guess in this case, I should use ContentControl as my FrameworkElemnt container. Please tell me ContentControl.Content = x is a simple assignment:)

Comment: @sun1991: Well, it's a dependency property assignment, so I still wouldn't call it "simple".  You could have a two-way binding applied to the Content property and the update would be pushed to another object.  ContentControl doesn't do value coercion like Frame does, though, so it should at least *act* like a simple property assignment :).

Answer (score 0):

See [WPF Frame, Content and ContentRendered](http://timl.net/2008/02/wpf-frame-content-and-contentrendered.html)

Your Frame will however never be rendered since it is not part of any visual tree. Below sample works as expected.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="FrameTest.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <Frame Name="_frame" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        FrameworkElement fe = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("WpfFrameContentProblem.Page1")) as FrameworkElement;

        _frame.Content = fe;
        _frame.ContentRendered += 
            (sender, e) => 
                MessageBox.Show("Type of content = " + (sender as Frame).Content.GetType()); 
    }
}
```